# C# Order by in foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC C#.

Here is a ready and working code (the part of the working code).

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{            
    <div style="height: 200px; ">
        @Html.Raw(@item.Description)
    </div>
}
```

The problem is the Description is not displayed on the page in the proper order is. So, the order of `<div>`s should be slightly different.

How to modify the code so it works properly?

The order of the `Description` field should be ordered by `Order` column.

Comment: Can't you just order it in your controller before sending it to the page?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534966.aspx) extension method on IEnumerable in System.Linq namespace

```
@foreach (var item in Model.OrderBy(i => i.Order))
{            
    <div style="height: 200px; ">
        @Html.Raw(@item.Description)
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to add: `<add namespace="System.Data.Linq" />` to your web.config.

Comment: This would work, but generally with MVC the role of the view is to just display data. IMO the logic behind ordering the items to be displayed should be handled by the controller. (You'd do the `.OrderBy` there.)

Comment: @Max - I tried your comment because linq wasn't working in my view despite referencing it with a using statement. It caused my app to not start with error: *The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data'* so I removed it. Strangely linq now appears to be working in my view now anyway. It's like I had to add that to web.config then remove it before anything would work.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Linq OrderBy extension method

```
@foreach (var item in Model.OrderBy(i => i.Order))
{
}
```

Comment: Guillaume was too quick! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Directly use orderby

```
@foreach (var item in Model.OrderBy(i => i.Order))
{            
    <div style="height: 200px; ">
        @Html.Raw(@item.Description)
    </div>
}
```